# Sweepstakes Probability

Tags: probability

Is there a way to determine the probability of winning a particular sweepstakes with only the following information:

- the estimated odds of winning are $1$ in $13,000$
- contestants must be owners (property holders) within the corporation running the sweepstakes and the total number of owners is $222,600$
- each owner can enter the sweepstakes up to $6$ times
- there is one grand prize and three runner-up prizes

Comment: What does "estimated odds of winning are 1 in 13,000" mean?  Does it mean 1 in 13,000 per entrance?  And does it mean the odds of winning at all, or the odds of winning the grand prize?

Answer (score 1):

If the estimated odds of winning are $1$ in $13,000$ per entrance, then if you enter once, your odds of winning are $1:13000$, of course.

However, entering more than once, it's a bit more complicated.  It's easier to calculate the odds of you *not* winning, and subtract it from $1$.

The odds of you *not* winning once is $12999/13000$.  The odds of you *not* winning twice is $(12999/13000)^2$, and three times is $(12999/13000)^3$, etc.

We could then say we can calculate your odds of not winning $n(x)$, where $x$ is the number of entries, as $n(x) = (12999/13000)^x$.

However, you want to calculate the odds of winning $p(x)$

We know that $n(x) + p(x) = 1$ (Think about it.  The sum of the odds of not winning and the odds of winning equal up to 1, because there is a 100% chance that one or the other will happen).  So, $p(x) = 1 - n(x)$

So to calculate your odds of winning, you would use

$p(x) = 1 - (12999/13000)^x$

where $x$ is the amount of times you've entered.

If you enter 6 times, then your total odds are $\frac{2227329628937465077999}{4826809000000000000000000}$, which is about $0.0004614497$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it makes perfect sense.  This question is based on real contest, and they literally state that the odds of winning are 1:13,000 without indicating whether that applies per entrance or to which prize(s).  They probably should have been more specific, but again, thanks!

Comment: based on your math if you enter 13000 times you only have about 64% chance of winning which is not true.